# kendo ui grid prevent posting data on client side validation error

Tags: post, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, preventdefault

I have done some clientside validation.

```
 parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
            if (operation !== "read") {
                var valid = customValidation(options);
                console.log(valid);
                if (valid) {
                    return JSON.stringify({ discountPromotionViewModel: options });
                }
            }
        },
```

And if the customValidation method returns false i don't want the grid to post the data. Now it posts an empty model so it still reaches my controller. How do i prevent it from even posting the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your validation inside Grid's event `save`, then if it's invalid result prevent it with `e.preventDefault` function. It will prevent POST request to server.

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    // some grid configuration 
    save: function(e) {
        var model = e.model,
            valid = customValidation(model);
        if(!valid) e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```